# shared thread pool on different ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer instances

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a use case of a lot consumer groups (and one topic per consumer group), I hence have to create many ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer instances each one for one topic/consumergroup. But I would like them to share a common thread pool to keep control of the calls of kafkaconsumer.poll and also how the records are processed. Do you think it is relevant to do that with spring kafka or do I have to implement my own version instantiating myself KafakConsumers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pool won't help - the container currently uses a dedicated thread for each consumer. There is no support for sharing threads across containers.